# Two different objects with same code-scripts in Unity work differently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got this part of script

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Pause_Menu.retryed)
        {
            Debug.Log(this.name);
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
```

It is attached to two object, but no matter which object exists, the first of them is still will be not destroyed and console will stay empty and the second one will be destroyed and console will has his name. What kind of problem it can be?

And also strange thing. If I'm trying destroy the first and the second externally by `GameObject.Find()` I will find also one of them, like second even doesn't exist, but it does.

Comment: Destroy(this); will destroy the component, so if you intended to destroy the game object you need Destroy(gameObject);

Comment: @Everts Thanks. But then I don't understand, this method still works for the first object, but not the second. And if I replace it on `Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name);` and `Destroy(this.gameObject);` it doesn't change something

Comment: The first GameObject is inactive, or this component is disabled, or `Pause_Menu.retryed` is false.

Comment: @shingo Thanks, I thought the same, but I've checked literally hundred times, both of them are active

Answer (score 1):

Yah, the problem was in difference between gameObject and component, I used it wrong. Thanks everyone and especially @Everts!